# Reducing Output length by introducing new variables

Tags: variable-definitions, customization, output

I have outputs like  "expression/(1+3*c^2) +anotherexpression/(1+3*c^2)" and so on.

Is there any way to set 1/(1+3*c^2)=A where A is a new variable so that the output reads like "A*expression+A*anotherexpression"?

Thanks

Comment: [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) or you can just use `(n + m + k)/(1 + 3*c^2) + x/(1 + 3*c^2) /. {1/(1 + 3 c^2) -> A}`

Answer (score 0):

```
ReplaceAll[x/(1 + 3 c^2) + y/(1 + 3 c^2), 1/(1 + 3 c^2) -> z]
```

> x z + y z

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much :)